# What should I do about this unrecognized PHP process?

Tags: php

I'm hoping you might be able to give me some advice.

I'm new to linux system administration so go easy on me :)

Was doing some checks around the directory that's being served by nginx and noticed some files were set with permission 655. I started to tidy them up and decided to do some looking around. Ran 'w' command and noticed my terminal was running pts/1 but no sign of pts/0. I was spooked by that even after running pkill -u and relogging, was that something to be concerned about?

Also loaded htop and saw a few strange processes running that id not seen before. Two in particular that stood out:

1. ```
    PHP -- www
    +PHP -- www
    +PHP -- www
   ```
2. `fwupd`

I closed the two parent processes of (PHP -- www, fwupd) and disconnected the ethernet.

Connected to the kvm and went to the logs directory, did a quick look through logs but couldn't see anything obvious (though i do need to give it a another verbose search to best of ability).

I did notice a file in the logs directory called wtemp, belonging to the group wtemp, owned by root. I don't recognise this file or its group, and the time stamp shows that it was modified just before i disconnected the ethernet.

-

Whats your feeling on this, should i be worried? Is it possible a client has modified the image files, executed some privilege escalation and started a firmware update using fwupd to embed code?

Comment: Does your server usually run PHP? If yes, it might just be your web server doing it's thing. If not, it's likely compromised.

Comment: Nothing looks terribly out of the ordinary based on the limited information provided here. We cannot tell for sure without much more information, at which point this question is likely not suitable for this site.

Comment: System runs php7.2-fpm, i'm familiar with the general system processes only these were displaying a strange output in htop:   PHP == www

Answer (score 0):

> Was doing some checks around the directory that's being served by nginx and noticed some files were set with permission 655. I started to tidy them up and decided to do some looking around. Ran 'w' command and noticed my terminal was running pts/1 but no sign of pts/0. I was spooked by that even after running pkill -u and relogging, was that something to be concerned about?

It looks like the machine supposed to run a webserver with PHP enabled, isn't it ?

So the PHP processes ran by `www` user are quite normal: webserver is usually running under a low-privileges user like `www`, `www-data`, etc...

> fwupd

Regarding the `fwupd` process, did you google a bit about it ? 
It's an updater for firmware. Firmware may be for RAID adapters, wireless nic, high speed wired nic, etc...

Check your distro to see if this piece of software is usually installed by it. But, i really doubt that this may be a malware.

> I did notice a file in the logs directory called wtemp, belonging to the group wtemp, owned by root. I don't recognise this file or its group, and the time stamp shows that it was modified just before i disconnected the ethernet.

One more time, did you googled a bit ? 
First, it is not `wtemp` but `wtmp`...
And it's just **THE** file used to record login/logout on every Linux (and maybe others Unix).

> Whats your feeling on this, should i be worried? Is it possible a client has modified the image files, executed some privilege escalation and started a firmware update using fwupd to embed code?

Look at the config file for this software.
Look at logs.
And, as i previously said, look if this software is shipped by your distro or not.

> I'm new to linux system administration so go easy on me :)

My first advice: search by yourself before asking and, when asking, be exhaustive ! This mean joining configuration files, logs, more detailled `ps` output, etc....